# Display does not blank on a Thinkpad T61

Tags: 10.04, screensaver

I have Ubuntu Lucid with kernel 2.6.35 on a Thinkpad T61. In the power management settings I set it up to blank the display after 2 minutes. This works right after I log in, but after a few hours of active use, closing applications and then walking away from the computer, the display won't ever blank until I log out and log in again. The screensaver, although enabled, activates only in the first few hours after logging in.

What can be the root cause of the problem?

- Incorrect screensaver or blanking settings cannot be the root cause, because these features work with the current settings right after logging in.
- User-visible applications (such as Firefox, Chrome, their Flash player or Skype) cannot be the root cause, because the screen doesn't blank even after I quit these. (Verified with `ps ax`.)

Is there a workaround?

How do I debug the problem? Is there a tool which displays a counter like *1:57 seconds until blanking*?

Please note that in this question I don't care about sleep, suspend or hibernate -- I care only about blanking the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched for hours and found two ways:

**Bash Scripts**: Here is a thread that has 2 ways. Post #7 is when the answers begin: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11738584#7

**Easier way**: [Stop using `gnome-power-manager`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/447728/comments/22):

1. Install `xfce4-power-manager`
2. Don't do anything to `gnome-power-manager`. Keep it in your system and ignore it like an annoying classmate. If you uninstall it, it will uninstall vital Ubuntu components.
3. Go to `System > Preferences > Startup Applications`

   - Find: `Power Management` and click `Edit`. Change: `gnome-power-manger` to `xfce4-power-manger`. Save. (If you add in a custom `Startup Applications` entry for xfce4-power-manager, it may not start. Don't know why that happens.  Editing the original `Power Management` is more reliable.)
4. Hit `Alt-F2` and run command `xfce4-power-manager-settings`.  Change the settings.
5. Reboot.
6. Downside:

   - The screen will darken/turn off during video apps because `gnome-screensaver` does not tell `xfce4-power-manager` to inhibit itself during video playback.
   - If the `xfc4-power-manager` works, but is unreliable, you might want to upgrade to version 1.0+ using this ppa: ppa:alexx2000/xfce
   - If that still doesn't work, change `gnome-screensaver` to `xscreensaver`.
   - If that still doesn't work, use my last option: Spend more than a week trying out different OSes, give up, and upgrade to Ubuntu/Gnome-Shell 11.10.  This problem has been solved there. Interestingly, Ubuntu 11.10 uses `xscreensaver` and not `gnome-screensaver`.

Comment: Thank you for this well-researched answer. I always wanted to get rid of gnome-power-manager, but I didn't know my options to replace it with.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by checking that gnome-screensaver is still running:

```
[user@host] ~> ps ax |grep screen
 1939 ?        Ss     0:06 gnome-screensaver
```

If it is running kill it with '`kill [pid]`' and restart it with '`gnome-screensaver --debug`'